# Adding string arrays in protocol buffers

Tags: protocol-buffers

I want to add string array in protocol buffer message, which I am not able to do. I have written as below

```
repeated string data = 1[packed=true];
```

I got the below error:

```
[packed = true] can only be specified for repeated primitive fields.
```

I could able to do it for int arrays with same syntax. I am confused why the string is considered as non-primitive type.
Can anyone help me please.?
Thanks !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Refer to the section "Specifying Field Rules" of the the [Protobuf Documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#simple). Essentially, packing *only* makes sense for numeric fields.

Preserving a quote for prosperity:

> For historical reasons, repeated fields of basic numeric types aren't encoded as efficiently as they could be. New code should use the special option [packed=true] to get a more efficient encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So can't we do it for string types.?

Comment: Just remove `[packed=true]`. Also, read the documentation, between the error message and that this shouldn't be a question.

Comment: So is anyone know why only primitive fields can be used with **packed** ?

Comment: This is why only primitive fields can use packed:
https://groups.google.com/g/protobuf/c/PMHGPi3njP0